# Why do we need the directly call in a thread-safe call block?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

Refer the thread-safe call tutorial at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx), have a look at following statments:

```
// InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
// calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
// If these threads are different, it returns true.
if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired) { 
    SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
    this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
} else {
    this.textBox1.Text = text;
}
```

Of course, I've used it many times in my codes, and understand a little why to use it.
But I still have some unclear questions about those statements, so anybody help me to find them out, please.

The questions are:

1. Will the code can run correctly with the statements in the if body only? I tried and seems it just cause the problem if the control is not initialize completely. I don't know is there more problem?
2. Which the advantage of calling method directly (else body) instance via invoker? Does it save resource (CPU, RAM) or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Still don't have a best answer, does anyone have something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you always run just the first part of the `if` statement, it will always be fine, as `Invoke` already checks if you're on the UI thread.

   1. The reason you don't want to do this is that `Invoke` has to do a a lot of work to run your method, even if you're already on the right thread. Here's what it has to do (extracted from the source of Control.cs):

      - Find the marshaling control via an upward traversal of the parent control chain
      - Check if the control is an ActiveX control and, if so, demand unmanaged code permissions
      - Work out if the call needs to be invoked asynchronously to avoid potential deadlock
      - Take a copy of the calling thread's execution context so the same security permissions will be used when the delegate is finally called
      - Enqueue the method call, then post a message to invoke the method, then wait (if synchronous) until it completes

None of the steps in the second branch are required during a direct call from the UI thread, as all the preconditions are already guaranteed, so it's definitely going to be faster, although to be fair, unless you're updating controls very frequently, you're very unlikely to notice any difference.

Comment: I'm interested in the way that you find the working out (extracting source - as you said)... Can you tell me how?

Comment: I have Resharper and Reflector installed on my PC, so I'm not sure which is doing it for me, but I'm pretty sure that even if you don't have either of these, Visual Studio will download the source from its symbol servers - all you need to do is right-click on the method and select "Go to Declaration". If that doesn't work, look at the settings under Tools,Options,Debugging,Symbols.

Answer (score 2):

You can of course always call using the Invoker, but:

- It usually makes the code more verbose and difficult to read.
- It is less efficient as there are several extra layers to contend with (setting up delegates, calling the dispatcher and so on).

If you are sure you'll always be on the GUI thread, you can just ignore the above checks and call directly.

Comment: I love your first advise, thanks. I'm mentioning the thread-safe, means it can be used in the other threads, not only GUI thread.